# Making a HTTP Web Request - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make a http request to a web server - the link I want to activate is

```
http://webserver/cgi-bin/fccgi.exe?w3exec=web.programname&w3serverpool=fcserverpool&optid=headline
```

It can't be a hyperlink as I don't want the page to go anywhere just make that request to that server/

Is this done through httpwebrequest? ...anyone know of a good example in asp.net (vb)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just do something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://webserver/cgi-bin/fccgi.exe?w3exec=web.programname&w3serverpool=fcserverpool&optid=headline");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (response) {
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

   reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.

> Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```